# SwiftUI macOS List with double click, selection is not working well

Tags: macos, swiftui

When implementing a `List` in `SwiftUI` on macOS, it seems that a double click TapGesture is messing up the selection. I can select 'outside' the text, but clicking 'on' the text is not working. When commenting out the TapGesture, the selection is working again.

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String { name }
    let name: String
}

class Manager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var data = [Item]()
    @Published var selection = Set<Item>()
    
    init() {
        data = [
            .init(name: "TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText-A"),
            .init(name: "TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText-B"),
            .init(name: "TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText-C"),
            .init(name: "TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText-D"),
            .init(name: "TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText-E")
        ]
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var manager = Manager()
    @State var selection = Set<Item>()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(manager.data, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { item in
            Text(item.name)
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
                    print("Double clicked", item.name)
                })
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: ClicksRecording]

A possible workaround is to use a `simultaneousGesture`, but setting the selection this way `selection = Set([item])` feels awkward.

```swift
List(manager.data, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { item in
    Text(item.name)
        .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
            print("Double clicked", item.name)
        })
        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
            selection = Set([item])
        })
}
```

Worth noting also, that if the `selection` is not a `Set<Item>`, but a `Set<String>` (meaning the `data` itself is not an `Item`, but a `String`), selection is working well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems .gesture consumes the users action.
May be you need some more selection logic.

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @StateObject var manager = Manager()

        var body: some View {
            List(manager.data, id: \.self, selection: $manager.selection) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .gesture(
                      TapGesture(count:1)
                        .onEnded({
                            print("Selected: \(item.name)")
                            manager.selection.removeAll()
                            manager.selection.insert(item)
                        })
                    )
                    .highPriorityGesture(
                      TapGesture(count:2)
                        .onEnded({
                            print("Double clicked: \(item.name)")
                        })
                    )
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's somewhat similar to the added `.simultaneousGesture` no? At any case, it very laggy, there's a noticeable time pass between the click and the selection